# Как получить привязку из view model?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

Как задать привязку для textbox к переменной которая содержится в файле view model(vm.cs)??

```
  <Window.DataContext>
    <local:VM/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Window.Resources>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
         <StackPanel>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Realties}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn MaxWidth="200" Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                             <TextBox Text="{Binding ???????}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

View model(vm.cs)

```
public class VM : VMBase
{
    ObservableCollection<Realty> _Realties =new ObservableCollection<Realty>(DataBase.Get());
    public ObservableCollection<Realty> Realties
    {
        get => _Realties;
        set
        {
            _Realties = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    string _NameFilter;
    public string NameFilter
    {
        get => _NameFilter;
        set
        {
        _NameFilter = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Datagrid привязал к свойству Realties, а textbox к свойству NameFilter не получается

Comment: Что значит "переменная, которая содержится в файле"? Это член класса? Нестатический? Публичный? Свойство?

Comment: @АндрейNOP, переписал вопрос.

Comment: `{Binding DataContext.NameFilter, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}`

Comment: @АндрейNOP, напишите в ответ, я помечу решением

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помог ответ от @АндрейNOP:

```
{Binding DataContext.NameFilter, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}
```